# multibib - combing citations of different types

Tags: subdividing, multibib

I am using `multibib` for a document with two different types of references.
To this end, I have defined

```
\newcites{R}{Own publications}
```

which adds a prefix "R" to references from that group when citing with `\citeR`.

Does anyone know how to combine references in the form

`\cite{key1,key2,key3}` giving [1,2,R3]?

Not sure if a wrapper for the cite command would work?

Comment: This isn't so easy. `cite` uses \jobname.aux and `citeR` uses `R.aux`. You can do what you want with biblatex.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid biblatex, but maybe it is a good reason to switch from bibtex.

Answer (score 3):

Problems like this one can be quite easily solved by switching to `biblatex`, while they are almost impossible with `multibib`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I found a simple work-around.

All you need is to add another bibliography that is not used in order to have a `\cite` command which does not add keys to either of your real bibs. Then, you can manually add the references to the bibs by using the `\nocite` commands. Your example will look like this:

```
\newcites{R}{Own publications}
\newcites{trash}{foo} % auxiliary cite command
\newcommand\mycite[2]{\citetrash{#1,#2}\nocite{#1}\nociteR{#2}} % new cite command
...
\mycite{key1,key2}{key3}
```

You will have an `trash.aux` file generated, but as long as this does not trouble you, it does the trick.

Comment: This doesn't scale well if you have too many different bibs but it works.