# Bibliography with different sections

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

A way of creating bibliography in latex is

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{} ... 

\end{thebibliography}
```

In this bibliography, I wanted to make different sections for "English books, German books, Research Papers etc." How can we make different lists in such way?

Writing `\section{}` within the `\begin{thebibliography}` and  `\end{thebibliography}` creates an error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  In a standard document this does not produce an error, but the section heading is indented to align with the bib items.

Comment: You might want to check [this topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45131/multibib-combing-citations-of-different-types).

Comment: Look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37649/manual-bibliography-separated-or-multiple-parts/37651#37651

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45131/4918 (as said by masu and DG')

Comment: You have more than one choice to do similar things. Have a look at the CTAN topic [bibtex-multi](http://www.ctan.org/topic/bibtex-multi) or use `biblatex`.